# cannot insert NULL into ("ESB"."ADDRESS_API"."LABEL_NAME_MAP")

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Attempting to hit the Customers end point and the API keeps rejecting my request with this extremely nondescript error:

```
<ErrorCode>-3002</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDesc>cannot insert NULL into ("ESB"."ADDRESS_API"."LABEL_NAME_MAP")</ErrorDesc>
<DBErrorCode>01400</DBErrorCode>
```

Here is the sample XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<Add RequestId='47e1633341s4521a24e269ad12ab3f6' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns='http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2'>
  <ExternalRealmId>111111111</ExternalRealmId>
  <Object xsi:type='Customer'>
    <TypeOf>Organization</TypeOf>
    <Name>SampleCustomer</Name>
    <Address>
      <Line1>123 E. Fake St</Line1>
      <Line2>Suite 1</Line2>
      <City>Somewhere</City>
      <Country>USA</Country>
      <CountrySubDivisionCode>FL</CountrySubDivisionCode>
      <PostalCode>12345</PostalCode>
      <Default>true</Default>
      <Tag>Billing</Tag>
    </Address>
    <Phone>
      <DeviceType>LandLine</DeviceType>
      <FreeFormNumber>123-456-4563</FreeFormNumber>
      <Default>true</Default>
      <Tag>Main</Tag>
    </Phone>
    <DBAName>Sample Customer</DBAName>
    <AcctNum>51f2ce86134c03000a000155</AcctNum>
  </Object>
</Add>
```

Any suggestions? These exceptions are super confusion. I found the one related to `"ESB"."PHONE_API"."LABEL_NAME_MAP"` was related to an empty phone number field. That isn't the case with this request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You edited your post to reflect a correct tag, so this answer may no longer be relevant**

My first guess would be that, per the [documentation](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/customer), the Address/Tag node allowable values are defined by the PhysicalAddressLabelType enum.

> Tag   - String - Tag (or label) that identifies the use of the address. The
>   values allowed are defined in the PhysicalAddressLabelType.

If you look at the [allowable values](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/062_enumerations/physicaladdresslabeltype), you'll see the only allowable values are:

- Billing
- Shipping

But you specified:

- Office

Can you try specifying a valid value?

Likewise, you're specifying an invalid Tag for the Phone node as well. The allowable values are here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/062_enumerations/telephonenumberlabeltype

But you've specified:

- Main

Can you try specifying a valid value?

Comment: That was it, I realized it after posting.

Comment: No problem - can you mark my answer as accepted if you feel it's correct? That will help other people down the line know it was an accepted/correct answer.